# jQuery get value of input datetime-local

Tags: jquery

I need to get the value from input datetime-local, but the variable is empty, whereas everything is ok with text inputs. Here is code:

```
<script>
var datetimeval = $("#datetime").val();
var textval = $("#text").val();
</script>
<input id='text' type='text' />
<input id='datetime' type='datetime-local' />
```

Could you tell me please, how to fix it?

Comment: you need to add the script after adding the input elements

Comment: Have you debugged your code? What errors do you get?

Comment: you wrap the code inside document.ready http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: I cannot get the datetime even so: jsfiddle.net/t89q3cfc/3

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this

```
<input id='text' type='text' value="test"/>
<input id='datetime' type='datetime-local' />
<script>
var datetimeval = $("#datetime").val();
var textval = $("#text").val();
alert(textval); 
alert(datetimeval);
</script>
```

**Demo:** [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sid_m/t89q3cfc/1/)

**Note:** I gave default value to *text* input textbox

Comment: Thanks for reply. But I cannot get the datetime even so: http://jsfiddle.net/t89q3cfc/3/

Comment: @egorfadeev: you want to get current date time in textbox or the value of textbox that user has entered?

Comment: I need to get the value from <input id='datetime' type='datetime-local' /> when I click on button

Comment: @egorfadeev : then what's the problem i get the value of your textbox after i enter both date and time.

Answer (score 1):

You should set its value of all parts, including y-m-d h:m, especially "h:m". It's ok for my case.